# Dynamic subsetting depending on values in R

Tags: r, dynamic, subset

i have a data frame with the next structure

```
    Id    Flag    value1   value2
    123    1       10        3.4
    124    1        5        1.2
    125    0       19        8.4
    126    1        8        1.2
    127    0       17        6.5
    128    2        1       -6.5
```

I need to separate the data frame into 'n' subsets depending in only the name of the column, where 'n' is the distinct values of the columns, i would expect the following:

```
    dataframe1
    Id    Flag    value1   value2
    123    1       10        3.4
    124    1        5        1.2
    126    1        8        1.2

    dataframe2
    Id    Flag    value1   value2
    125    0       19        8.4
    127    0       17        6.5

    dataframe3
    Id    Flag    value1   value2
    128    2        1       -6.5
```

Since this is going inside a function, I only know the name of the column and the distinct values it can take, I've tried:

```
    dataFrame$column==value
```

but I would need to do this for every value, and the values are dynamic in length depending on the name of the column.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, `split` is your friend.

```
splitbycol <- function(df, colname) {
   split(df, df[[colname]])
}

splitbycol(df, "Flag")
## $`0`
##    Id Flag value1 value2
## 3 125    0     19    8.4
## 5 127    0     17    6.5
## 
## $`1`
##    Id Flag value1 value2
## 1 123    1     10    3.4
## 2 124    1      5    1.2
## 4 126    1      8    1.2
## 
## $`2`
##    Id Flag value1 value2
## 6 128    2      1   -6.5
```

Then, if you'd like to make each of the data frames a separate "variable", call e.g.

```
subdf <- splitbycol(df, "Flag")
for (i in seq_along(subdf))
   assign(paste0("df", i), subdf[[i]])
df1
##    Id Flag value1 value2
## 3 125    0     19    8.4
## 5 127    0     17    6.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solves entirely the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach avoiding `for` loop

```
> List <- split(df, df$Flag)                            # split 
> names(List) <- paste0("dataframe", seq_along(List))   # naming (use seq_along better)
> list2env(List, envir=.GlobalEnv)                      # from list to data.frame

> dataframe1
#    Id Flag value1 value2
#3 125    0     19    8.4
#5 127    0     17    6.5
> dataframe2
#   Id Flag value1 value2
#1 123    1     10    3.4
#2 124    1      5    1.2
#4 126    1      8    1.2
> dataframe3
#    Id Flag value1 value2
# 6 128    2      1   -6.5
```

Comment: Also, it would be worth to mention that it is better to keep the data.frame's in a list than as a separated variables in the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, so you're saying what I should have a dataFrameList where each entry is a data frame?